# How to sort two dimensional array lexicographically?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, java-9

Assuming we have a two-dimensional array as follows:

```
int[][] source = {
  {   3,  5,  6,  1},
  {   3,  3,  5, -6},
  {  -1, -3, -5, -6},
  { 124, 43, 55, -66}
};
```

how do we sort the multidimensional array `source` *lexicographically*?

So, as a result, I'd expect it to be:

```
[ [ -1, -3, -5,  -6], 
  [  3,  3,  5,  -6], 
  [  3,  5,  6,   1], 
  [124, 43, 55, -66] ]
```

a lot of questions on this site seem to only suggest sorting by the first element of each array or second, third etc. but not taking in consideration the entire array.

Comment: Very nice question. I tried to format example array in a way to let "lexicographically" be easier to understand by swapping rows starting with 3 so it would be more obvious that in such case value form next column is supposed to be used at comparison. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of JDK9, there's a new method called [`Arrays.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#compare-int:A-int:A-) which allows you to compare two given arrays *lexicographically*.

Short description of [`Arrays.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#compare-int:A-int:A-) from the documentation:

> If the two arrays share a common prefix then the lexicographic
>   comparison is the result of comparing two elements, as if by
>   Integer.compare(int, int), at an index within the respective arrays
>   that is the prefix length. Otherwise, one array is a proper prefix of
>   the other and, lexicographic comparison is the result of comparing the
>   two array lengths.

Given you want to *modify* the `source` array then using `Arrays.sort` should suffice:

```
Arrays.sort(source, Arrays::compare);
```

Given you want a *new* array as a result then I'd go the stream way:

```
int[][] sorted = Arrays.stream(source)
                       .sorted(Arrays::compare)
                       .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

Comment: In Java 8, you can use `Comparator.comparing(IntBuffer::wrap)` as stand-in for `Arrays::compare`. And, by the way, for an array initializer, you don’t need `new int[][]` nor `new int[]`.

Answer (score -1):

First sort each ArrayList in the Array.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> allSubset = new ArrayList<>();

for(ArrayList<Integer> row : allSubset) {
     Collections.sort(row);
}
```

Second sort the whole ArrayList in lexicographically.

```
allSubset.sort((ArrayList<Integer> o1, ArrayList<Integer> o2) -> {
            if(o2.size() == 0) return 1;
            int min = Math.min(o1.size(), o2.size());
            int i;
            for(i = 0; i < min - 1; i++) {
                if(o1.get(i).equals(o2.get(i))) continue;
                return o1.get(i).compareTo(o2.get(i));
            }
            return o1.get(i).compareTo(o2.get(i));
        });
```

or

```
    Collections.sort(allSubset, (ArrayList < Integer > first, ArrayList < Integer > second) -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < first.size() && i < second.size(); i++) {
            if (first.get(i) < second.get(i))
                return -1;
            if (first.get(i) > second.get(i))
                return 1;
        }
        if (first.size() > second.size())
            return 1;
        return -1;
    });
```

Comment: Did you try your solution with the input in the question and compared it to the expected output?

Comment: Yes @JohannesKuhn, for this question. don't sort the inner array. just sort the whole array.

```
        System.out.println(lexicographicallySort(Arrays.asList(
                Arrays.asList(3,  5,  6,  1),
                Arrays.asList(3,  3,  5, -6),
                Arrays.asList(-1, -3, -5, -6),
                Arrays.asList(124, 43, 55, -66)
        )));
```

output: [[-1, -3, -5, -6], [3, 3, 5, -6], [3, 5, 6, 1], [124, 43, 55, -66]]

Comment: @JohannesKuhn, in the above example, all inner array size is same. But you can try with empty array and different size array.

like: [ [], [4, 5], [12], [4, 5, 6] ]